# Sum of elements based on grouping an element using scala?

Tags: scala

I have following scala list-

```
    List((192.168.1.1,8590298237), (192.168.1.1,8590122837), (192.168.1.1,4016236988),
 (192.168.1.1,1018539117), (192.168.1.1,2733649135),  (192.168.1.2,16755417009), 
(192.168.1.1,3315423529), (192.168.1.2,1523080027), (192.168.1.1,1982762904), 
(192.168.1.2,6148851261), (192.168.1.1,1070935897), (192.168.1.2,276531515092), 
(192.168.1.1,17180030107), (192.168.1.1,8352532280), (192.168.1.3,8590120563), 
(192.168.1.3,24651063), (192.168.1.3,4431959144), (192.168.1.3,8232349877), 
(192.168.1.2,17493253102), (192.168.1.2,4073818556),   (192.168.1.2,42951186251))
```

I want following output-

```
List((192.168.1.1, sum of all values of 192.168.1.1),
(192.168.1.2, sum of all values of 192.168.1.2),
(192.168.1.3, sum of all values of 192.168.1.3))
```

How do I get sum of second elements from list by grouping on first element using scala??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you can use the `groupBy` function in Scala. You do, in your input data however have some issues, the ip numbers or whatever that is must be Strings and the numbers Longs. Here is an example of the `groupBy` function:

```
val data = ??? // Your list
val sumList = data.groupBy(_._1).map(x => (x._1, x._2.map(_._2).sum)).toList
```

If the answer is correct accept it or comment and I'll explain some more.